# saving JSON response locally in database Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data, nsdictionary

I have a questioAnswer responseObject for a GET API request:

{"7d2c591c-9056-405c-9509-03266842b7e5"=();"f884a7d1-f9d9-4563-bb6e-94538664f3bd"=test;}

how to save it locally in the database against a particular survey uuid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys! but I tried creating database using FMDB(since it was already integrated) and it creates new answer table properly but am having trouble with saving the above dictionary as its having dynamic Key- value pairing.

Answer (score 2):

You can save it in session.

Setting:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userDefaults setObject:value 
                 forKey:key];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Getting:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
```

**Edit**

Just to expound on all the steps you actually need to perform to add Core Data to a project that previously did not have it:

**Step 1: Add the Framework**

Click on your app target (on the left pane its the top icon with the name of your app) then go to the 'Build Phases' tab then on 'Link Binary With Libraries', click the little '+' at the bottom then find 'CoreData.framework' and add it to your project

Then either import coredata on all the objects you need it (the non-sexy way) using:

**Swift**

```
import CoreData
```

**Objective C**

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

or add the import below the common imports in your .pch file (much more sexy) like this:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#endif
```

**Step 2: Add the Data Model**

To add the .xcdatamodel file right click/control-click on your files in the right pane (like in a Resources folder for safe keeping) and select to Add a New File, Click the Core Data tab when selecting your file type then Click 'Data Model', give it a name and click Next and Finish and it will add it to your project. When you click on this Model object you will see the interface to add the Entities to your project with any relationships you want.

**Step 3: Update App Delegate**

In **Swift** on AppDelegate.swift

```
//replace the previous version of applicationWillTerminate with this
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

func saveContext () {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    if managedObjectContext != nil {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges && !managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

// #pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
    if !_managedObjectContext {
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator != nil {
            _managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
            _managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        }
    }
    return _managedObjectContext!
}
var _managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel {
    if !_managedObjectModel {
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("iOSSwiftOpenGLCamera", withExtension: "momd")
        _managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
    }
    return _managedObjectModel!
}
var _managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel? = nil

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator {
    if !_persistentStoreCoordinator {
        let storeURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("iOSSwiftOpenGLCamera.sqlite")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        _persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        if _persistentStoreCoordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
            /*
            Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            Typical reasons for an error here include:
            * The persistent store is not accessible;
            * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
            Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
            If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.
            If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
            * Simply deleting the existing store:
            NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(storeURL, error: nil)
            * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter:
            [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true}
            Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.
            */
            //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator!
}
var _persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = nil

// #pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL {
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.endIndex-1] as NSURL
}
```

In Objective C make sure to add these objects to AppDelegate.h

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
 @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
 @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

 - (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory; // nice to have to reference files for core data
```

Synthesize the previous objects in AppDelegate.m like this:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Then add these methods to AppDelegate.m (make sure to put the name of the model that you added in the spots shown):

```
- (void)saveContext{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"NAMEOFYOURMODELHERE" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"NAMEOFYOURMODELHERE.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

 #pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

**Step 4: Get the Data Objects to the ViewControllers Where You Need the Data**

**Option 1. Use the App Delegate's ManagedObjectContext from VC (Preferred and Easier)**

As suggeted by @brass-kazoo - Retrieve a reference to AppDelegate and its managedObjectContext via:

**Swift**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
 appDelegate.managedObjectContext
```

**Objective C**

```
 [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

**Option 2. Create ManagedObjectContext in your VC and have it match AppDelegate's from the AppDelegate (Original)**

Only showing old version for Objective C since much easier to use the preferred method

in the ViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

In the ViewController.m

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
```

In the AppDelegate, or class where the ViewController is created set the managedObjectContext to be the same as the AppDelegate one

```
ViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

If you want the viewcontroller using Core Data to be a FetchedResultsController then you'll need to make sure this stuff is in your ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
  NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
  NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
}

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

And this is in ViewController.m

```
@synthesize fetchedResultsController, managedObjectContext;
```

After all of that you can now use this managedObjectContext to run all the usual fetchRequests needed for CoreData goodness! Enjoy

Comment: This is an excellent solution as long as you don't have too many. If there are hundreds or thousands of these, you'll need to consider other ways to persist the data, such as:  Core Data, Realm, or Firebase.

Comment: Yes you right!.. Then you have to integrate coredata or realm database

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store in coredata (to use offline), then just create an entity and insert tuples into the entity.

Just follow the below link for Core data tutorial : 
[Core data Tutorial AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/)

If you can also use UserDefaults to store particular data.

Hope it helps